# Can the core data kill the app when the iOS app is back ground in very less time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

i am unable to keep the app live in background more than 4minutes.The app **suspends** after 4minutes. Is this happens because of **core data**? if **yes** any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that your app is suspended. You can extend it for a while if you need to finish the task but you can't executing tasks for ever in background. From Apple's website:

> Apps moving to the background are expected to put themselves into a
> quiescent state as quickly as possible so that they can be suspended
> by the system. If your app is in the middle of a task and needs a
> little extra time to complete that task, it can call the
> beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: or
> beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method of the UIApplication
> object to request some additional execution time. Calling either of
> these methods delays the suspension of your app temporarily, giving it
> a little extra time to finish its work. Upon completion of that work,
> your app must call the endBackgroundTask: method to let the system
> know that it is finished and can be suspended.

Take a look at the full article [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

What exactly do you want to do in background?